# $\int_0^\infty \frac{x^a\ln(x)}{(x^2-bx+1)^{a+1}}{\rm d}x = 0$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

> Does
>   $$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^a\ln(x)}{(x^2-bx+1)^{a+1}}{\rm d}x = 0$$
>   for all real numbers $a > 0$ and $b < 2$?

I came across this conjecture by showing its validity for the positive integer values of $a$ only.

To derive the result for positive integer $a$, make the substitution $u=\frac1x$ on 
$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(1+x^k)}{x^2-bx+1}{\rm d}x $$

and we get
$$  \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(1+x^k)}{x^2-bx+1}{\rm d}x = \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(1+x^k)}{x^2-bx+1}{\rm d}x - k \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(x)}{x^2-bx+1}{\rm d}x \\
\implies \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(x)}{x^2-bx+1}{\rm d}x = 0
$$

From here, we can use Leibniz's rule of integration (differentiating with respect to $b$) $n$ times to retrieve
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^n\ln(x)}{(x^2-bx+1)^{n+1}}{\rm d}x = 0$$

Yet I'm guessing that it is also valid for any real positive value of $a$ from numerical evidence. Complex methods are welcome but I won't really be familiar with them, so I would prefer sticking to real methods.

Comment: I am not quite sure: How do you get from $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(x)}{x^2-bx+1}{\rm d}x$$ to $$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^n\ln(x)}{(x^2-bx+1)^{n+1}}{\rm d}x$$? With respect to which parameter do you differentiate?

Comment: Differentiate with respect to $b$.

Comment: I would include this detail hence, at least to me, it was not  clear at all.

Comment: Same proof as [before](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3056117/44121).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it does. Just substitute $\displaystyle{x=\frac{1}{t}}$ to get: 
$$I=\int_0^\infty \frac{x^a\ln(x)}{(x^2-bx+1)^{a+1}}{\rm d}x=\int_\infty^0 \frac{1}{t^a} \frac{\ln\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)}{\left(\frac{1}{t^2}-\frac{b}{t}+1\right)^{a+1}}\frac{-dt}{t^2}$$
$$=\int_0^\infty \frac{t^{2a+2}\ln\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)}{\left(1-bt+t^2\right)^{a+1}}\frac{dt}{t^{a+2}}=\int_0^\infty \frac{t^a\ln\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)}{(t^2-bt+1)^{a+1}}dt=-I$$
$$I=-I\Rightarrow I=0$$

Comment: Omg I feel so dumb, thank you so much. Standard substitutions slip by me occasionally...

Comment: I like your derivation in your question! A small typo:$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(1+x^k)}{x^2-bx+1}{\rm d}x = \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(1+x^k)}{x^2-bx+1}{\rm d}x - \color{red}k \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(x)}{x^2-bx+1}{\rm d}x 
\implies \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(x)}{x^2-bx+1}{\rm d}x = 0$$